# Using UIC on Qt (c++)

Tags: c++, qt, designer

I'm looking for using Qt Designer and generate the cpp source corresponding to the .ui files.

After some researches, i've found that the UIC can do it.

[Here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/2.3/designer/chap2_3.html) is an example.

But there is no explanation about where to use the command .. I've tried to put it on .pro file an  on command line argument(on project parameters).
My command : 
*uic -i mainwindow.h -o fruit.cpp mainwindow.ui*

Answer (score 4):

If you have `foo.ui` and want to generate the `ui_foo.h` file, you should add the `foo.ui` to the `FORMS` list in the `.pro` file:

```
FORM += foo.ui
```

If you want to use `uic` manually from the command line, you can do so as well:

```
/path/to/my/qt/bin/uic -i foo.h -o ui_foo.h
```

You then include the generated header to use the `Ui::Foo` class:

```
// foo.h
...
#include "ui_foo.h"

class Foo : public QWidget {
  Ui::Foo ui; // no need for it to be a pointer!
  ...
public:
  explicit Foo(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QWidget{parent} {
    ui.setupUi(this);
  }
};
```